# Why is Transaction being Elevated to Distributed Transaction (MSDTC), Even after Closing 1st Connection and then Opening the 2nd Connection

Tags: c#, ado.net, transactionscope, sqlconnection

I am trying this code which I think SHOULD NOT elevate/promote the TransactionScope to Distributed Transaction (MSDTC), because I read somewhere that MSDTC only happens under 2 conditions, 
1. when we have a Nested TransactionScope 
2. If we try to open 2 SIMULTANEOUS Connections to 2 different Sources within the same TransactionScope

But I am Closing the Earlier Connection and then Opening the New Connection to the Different Source, but still it is Promoting the Transaction to a Distributed one.

The Error I get is "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions."

Here is the Code:

```
                var options = new TransactionOptions()
                {
                    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead,
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
                };

                using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
                {

                    // Connection To Server Database
                    string connectionString = "Server=188.188.188.188;Database=SomeDb;User=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword;Trusted_Connection=false;Connection Timeout=30;Persist Security Info=False";
                    SqlConnection conn1 = null;
                    try
                    {
                        conn1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                        conn1.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (conn1 != null)
                        {
                            conn1.Close();
                            conn1.Dispose();
                            conn1 = null;
                        }
                    }

                    // Connection To Local Machine Database
                    string connectionString2 = "Server=MyPC\\SqlServer2014;Database=SomeDb;User=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword;Trusted_Connection=false;Connection Timeout=30;Persist Security Info=False";
                    SqlConnection conn2 = null;
                    try
                    {
                        conn2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString2);
                        conn2.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn2.Close();
                        conn2.Dispose();
                        conn2 = null;
                    }

                    scope.Complete();
                }
```

Comment: Because it already is a distributed transaction. It's *one transaction* that covers *two* connections. When it commits or rolls back it will have to commit or roll back changes made to *both* databases. If you don't want that, don't use the transaction scope to wrap both connections

Comment: In any case, the code isn't save. You can get rid of the entire `try/catch` block if you use a `using` block the way all docs and tutorials show. `SqlConnection.Dispose` calls `Close` and setting the variable to null isn't needed if the connections are *already* disposed

Comment: But you need MSDTC enabled in both, the Server and My Desktop Machine. For that you need to have the port 135 open. Most of the ISPs (Internet Service Providers) do not  allow the port 135 to be open on the network because of vulnerability to hackers. Also if the same code is used for Xamarin then there is no MSDTC Service on the Android phone.

Comment: This MSDTC concept is a pain in Everywhere :).

Comment: No it's not. *This* code is a clear bug though.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why would you need to connect to a remote database over an ISP, much less use *transactions* like this? The normal way is to use a web service, SOAP or HTTP, rather than exposing the database. Second, the two-phase commit protocol used in distributed transactions *demands* good connections. That's why they aren't used for mobile scenarios and nobody even tried to make that work. What works (with issues) but only for SOAP is, WS-Transactions. There's nothing similar for HTTP/REST

Comment: Are you trying to sync local and remote storage perhaps?

Comment: Yes i am using a TransactionScope at the user interface like a button click. Then various methods are called where some methods are interacting with server database and reading the records to a reader. The other methods interact with the local machine and insert those records got earlier in the reader.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you try to use one TransactionScope while using *two* connections, or what you expect to achieve from this. In fact, unless you want to *modify the remote database*, there's no reason for a transaction at all

Comment: Did you try use the  transaction per request/session/whatever pattern? That refers to *domain (business)* transactions on a *J2EE server*, not database transactions. Same goes for Unit of Work.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was generalising the methods. Now i think i will have to separate those methods and call the methods reading from the server outside the transactionscope and do the insert records within the transactionscope

Comment: What is transaction per request/session and where is it used

Comment: @Panagiotis you are right about my code though. I should actually doing this with the Using block.